# Run pppd automatically for incoming connections

Tags: pppd

I have my 1989 Mac SE/30 connecting into my Debian 10 router using PPP over a null modem USB RS232 adapter.

When I want to connect I first have to SSH into debian from another machine and run

```
# pppd nodetach /dev/ttyUSB0 57600 -crtscts
```

Furthermore, if the Mac disconnects then `pppd` quits and in order to reconnect I have to do the same all over again.

Is is possile to get `pppd` to listen on `ttyUSB0` automatically? And to stay up?

(All of the documentation I've found is intended for using PPP as a client for dial-up internet connections, not as a server.)

**Update**

```
mini31 # pwd
/etc/systemd/network
mini31 # ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 187 Jun 14 12:12 pppd-ttyUSB0.service
mini31 # cat pppd-ttyUSB0.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/pppd nodetach /dev/ttyUSB0 57600 -crtscts
Restart=always
RestartSec=0

[Unit]
Description=pppd on ttyUSB0 for SE/30
After=network.target
Wants=network.target
mini31 # systemctl status pppd-ttyUSB0
Unit pppd-ttyUSB0.service could not be found.
mini31 #
```

**Update 2**

Looks like `/etc/systemd/system` is the only folder that works.

Furthermore, you have to:

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
mini31 # systemctl status pppd-ttyUSB0
● pppd-ttyUSB0.service - pppd on ttyUSB0 for Macs
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pppd-ttyUSB0.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
mini31 # systemctl enable pppd-ttyUSB0
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.

Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
• A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
  .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
• A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
  a requirement dependency on it.
• A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
  D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
• In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
  instance name specified.
mini31 # systemctl start pppd-ttyUSB0
```

(Don't know what all that nonsense from `enable` is about.)

Comment: You need an Install section. Check [this](https://tuttlem.github.io/2018/02/03/create-a-systemd-daemon.html) for a basic service. You would then change the Restart policy. By the way, I love your setup.

Answer (score 1):

Create a *service* that runs this daemon. In systemd services, you can use the `Restart=` option to automatically start the service again when it exits.

```
[Service]
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/pppd nodetach /dev/ttyUSB0 57600 -crtscts
Restart=always
RestartSec=0
```

Your situation is actually very similar to `getty@.service`, only with pppd instead of getty, which normally waits for a login prompt at the specified tty. So it might be useful to look at that unit for inspiration – for example, you might want to make this a template unit (named `pppd@` and using `/dev/%i` as the device path); you might want to include `Conflicts=getty@%i.service` in the [Unit] section; and so on.

(Indeed in a 'sysvinit' environment I would've suggested creating an /etc/inittab entry for pppd, so that it would be automatically restarted by init just like getty is.)